# datatables with multiple filtering with comma numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hello I am using this datatable 
[here](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Right now the filter search Minimum d1 and Maximum d1 values is working as it should, but the problem is it can not handle values correct with commas, which is a required for this function.

Example: I want the filter to show results between 1.5 and 2.5, as of now it will show any numbers between 1.00 and 2.99,which is wrong.

What could be causing this? Am I missing a regex here?

also: it is possible to change the values from "," to "." meaning 1,5 or 1.5 is no problem in the data, if that will help anything.

Codes:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data\jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="data\jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="data\jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="data\custom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>Minimum d1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="min" name="min"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maximum d1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="max" name="max"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>M/Ø</th>
                  <th>Ww</th>
                  <th>Norm</th>
                  <th>d<sub>1</sub></th>
                  <th>d<sub>2</sub></th>
                  <th>h</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
      </table>
</body>


</html>
```

JS

```
/* Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {

    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    console.log(min);
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );


    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "data.txt"
} );

// Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
} );
```

Data.txt (Dummy data)

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      "",
      "ISO 7089 + 7090 (DIN 125-1 Pk A)",
      "1,1",
      "3",
      "0,3"
    ],

    [
    "1",
    "",
    "ISO 7092 (DIN 433 Pk A)",
    "1,1",
    "2,5",
    "0,3"
    ],

    [
    "1",
    "",
    "ISO 7092 (DIN 433 Pk A)",
    "2,6",
    "2,5",
    "0,3"
    ],

    [
    "1",
    "",
    "ISO 7092 (DIN 433 Pk A)",
    "1,1",
    "2,5",
    "0,3"
    ],



    [
    "1",
    "",
    "ISO 7092 (DIN 433 Pk A)",
    "1,4",
    "2,5",
    "0,3"
    ]



  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your min and max values are defined using parseInt, thus giving you integer numbers, while you want floating numbers.

I think you should replace

```
var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
```

With

```
var min = parseFloat($('#min').val().replace(',', '.'));
var max = parseFloat($('#max').val().replace(',', '.'));
```

Also, note the replace part because parseFloat won't handle comas as decimals separator, so your age data won't be parsed correctly. You also need to do the following :

```
var age = parseFloat(data[3].replace(',', '.')) || 0;
```